# Can stronger consumer grade magnets affect solar cells?

Tags: solar-cell, magnetics

Is there any evidence to suggest that stronger consumer grade magnets like the one in [this magnetic phone holder](https://niteize.com/mobile/steelie/steelier-dash-kit-plus) can negatively impact the efficacy of consumer grade solar cells like the one in [this TV remote](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09BKCWMSZ)?

It's likely that these items could come into close contact, and while I understand that these types of magnets don't really impact lithium batteries (lots of people have asked this question), I'm not sure about solar cells.

Comment: I can't see any physical mechanism by which it would do anything significant. All I can think is that you might get some splitting of electron levels that might make it ever so slightly less efficient (I'm talking a parts-per-billion change if any). Static magnetic fields don't really have much of an effect on things that aren't themselves relying on magnetic phenomena.

Comment: Sounds more like a weak excuse for the solar cell having insufficient ability to charge the battery under typical use conditions.

Comment: In practice no. An interesting effect is the diversion on charged extrea-terrestial particles by magnetic fields. This has been suggested as a **possible* manner in which power lines may concentrate incoming ionising radiation. You'd not notice it in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would not affect it electrically. A static magnetic field from a consumer grade magnet isn't strong enough to affect diodes or transistors. If there were any mechanical issues that could be a problem but beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1):

You'd possibly get some resistance increase due to the hall effect, but that's all I can think of. It would probably not be enough to be easily detected.